# Find the points through which this curve always pass

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, conic-sections, curves

Suppose I have a curve, in this case it's a parabola, and I've to find the points through which this curve always pass. The equation of the curve is
$$\left\{x-\frac{a}{2}(1+\sqrt3)\right\}^2+\left\{y-\frac{a}{2}(1+\sqrt3)\right\}^2=\frac{(x+y+a)^2}{2}$$

---

Since it was a MCQ I was able to get the right answer by putting in the values. But I want to know whether there is a proper method for these type of questions or not. The answers were $(a,0)$ and $(0,a)$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This equation gives set of curves, each of those correspond to some $a$. Maybe, the question is what are points common for all curves with various $a$?

Comment: If you replace $x$ and $y$, you get the same function, so the curve is symmetric about $y=x$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu this was not the real question...the real question involved two other parabolas and this curve is also a parabola

Comment: Then what is "fixed point" in context of the question?

Comment: What I think that the fixed point means a point...from where the curve will pass no matter what we put the value of x or y

Comment: The answers are the points where the parabola of focus $(\frac{a}{2}(1+\sqrt3),\frac{a}{2}(1+\sqrt3))$ and normalized directrix $\frac{x+y+a}{\sqrt2}=0$ intersect the axes. There are two more.

Comment: The curve will pass through $\left(0,\frac{\left(9+5 \sqrt{3}\right) a}{1+\sqrt{3}}\right)$ at any $a$

Comment: Please can you all elaborate your comments as answers as I'm not able to understand your conclusions

Comment: One can easily write equation in form $x=x(a,t)$, $y=y(a,t)$, then every point of kind $(x(a,t),y(a,t))$ at some $t$ will be the answer, for example $\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} a}{2-\sqrt{3}},\frac{4 \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right) a}{\sqrt{3}-1}\right)$, $\left(\frac{2}{3} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right) a,-\frac{a}{3}\right)$ and so on.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu pls elaborate ... how are those answers also coming?

Comment: A parametrization is $(-\frac{(\sqrt3-2) t^2+2 a t-\sqrt3 a^2}{4a},-\frac{(\sqrt3-2) t^2-2 a t-\sqrt3 a^2}{4 a})$ found by solving $\langle x-y-t,f\rangle,$ where $f$ is your parabola equation. (The vertex is then for $t=0.$) The $x$-axis intercepts are for $(-\frac{\sqrt3 a}{\sqrt3-2},0),(a,0)$ and the $y$-axis intercepts are for $(0,-\frac{\sqrt3 a}{\sqrt3-2}),(0,a),$ as you can see by setting the $y$- and $x$-coordinate of the parametrization to $0$ respectively and solve for $t$.